# TSQL How to get a date then the next date after from another column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have a query I'm trying to put together where I need to select a date then the next occurring date from a different column.

My select statement is:

```
Select tblOEEDownTime.LineNumber, 
tblOEEDownTime.SampleDate as 'Down Time',
tblOEEUpTime.Sampledate as 'Up Time', 
(DATEDIFF(minute, tblOEEDownTime.SampleDate, tblOEEUpTime.Sampledate )) as 'Minutes Down', 
tblOEEUpTime.Reason, 
tblOEEUpTime.Comment as DownTime 

from tblOEEDownTime JOIN 
tblOEEUpTime on tblOEEDownTime.LineNumber = tblOEEUpTime.LineNumber

where TblOEEDownTime.SampleDate > '2020-09-14' and TblOEEDownTime.LineNumber like '6427' and tblOEEUpTime.SampleDate > tblOEEDownTime.SampleDate
Group by tblOEEDownTime.LineNumber, tblOEEDownTime.SampleDate, tblOEEUpTime.SampleDate, tblOEEUpTime.Reason, TblOEEUptime.Comment
```

[Picture of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADoeq.png)

In the results picture I'd like my returned values to be the rows I have highlighted. More or less I would like the down time with the very next up time after the associated down time.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. A picture of data is not nearly as useful to us as DDL and usable sample data with corresponding expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cross apply` to fetch the single next uptime row for each downtime row.

**Sample data**

```
create table tblOEEDownTime
(
  LineNumber int,
  SampleDate datetime
);

insert into tblOEEDownTime (LineNumber, SampleDate) values
(6427, '2020-09-16 10:00:00'),
(6427, '2020-09-16 12:00:00'),
(6427, '2020-09-16 15:00:00');

select * from tblOEEDownTime;

create table tblOEEUpTime
(
  LineNumber int,
  SampleDate datetime,
  Reason nvarchar(20),
  Comment nvarchar(20)
);

insert into tblOEEUpTime (LineNumber, SampleDate, Reason, Comment) values
(6427, '2020-09-16 10:01:00', 'Replenish', null),
(6427, '2020-09-16 10:03:00', 'Testing', 'Drew'),
(6427, '2020-09-16 10:05:00', 'Cleaning', null),
(6427, '2020-09-16 12:05:00', 'Replenish', null),
(6427, '2020-09-16 12:08:00', 'Testing', 'Drew'),
(6427, '2020-09-16 12:10:00', 'Cleaning', null),
(6427, '2020-09-16 15:30:00', 'Cleaning', null);
```

**Solution**

```
select d.LineNumber,
       d.SampleDate as [Down Time],
       u.Sampledate as [Up Time],
       datediff(MI, d.SampleDate, u.Sampledate) as [Minutes Down],
       u.Reason,
       u.Comment as DownTime 
from tblOEEDownTime d
cross apply ( select top 1 u1.SampleDate, u1.Reason, u1.Comment
              from tblOEEUpTime u1
              where u1.LineNumber = d.LineNumber
                and u1.SampleDate > d.SampleDate
              order by u1.SampleDate ) u
where d.SampleDate > '2020-09-14'
  and d.LineNumber = 6427;
```

**Result**

```
LineNumber  Down Time               Up Time                 Minutes Down    Reason      DownTime
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- --------------- ----------- --------
6427        2020-09-16 10:00:00.000 2020-09-16 10:01:00.000 1               Replenish   null
6427        2020-09-16 12:00:00.000 2020-09-16 12:05:00.000 5               Replenish   null
6427        2020-09-16 15:00:00.000 2020-09-16 15:30:00.000 30              Cleaning    null
```

Interactive version: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0236933b605b14e3a474c94e54d3b701).